# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement - when run a query using node-oracledb

Tags: oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

I logged in as user AN and created a procedure in sql developer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE **viewSystemUsers**
AS 
  sysRefCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN sysRefCursor
  FOR 
    SELECT USERNAME, USER_ID, PASSWORD FROM dba_users;
    dbms_sql.return_result(sysRefCursor);
END;
```

And **executed it**, this worked normally. After that i **successfully connected** as the same user using **node-oracledb**:

```
  oracle.getConnection(
        {
            user : "AN",
            password: "AN123",
            connectString: "localhost:1521/orcl"
            
        }, 
        (error, **connection**) => {
                if(error){
                    console.error(error.message);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    console.log('connect sucessfully!');
```

But when i set the EXECUTE query:

```
**connection**.execute(
      `execute **viewSystemUsers**;`,
       (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                  console.error(err);
                  return;
            }
           console.log(result);
```

I received [Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement] { errorNum: 900, offset: 0 }.
Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does node-oracledb support `dbms_sql.return_result`? If it does not then you may need to use an `OUT` parameter on the procedure (which would be the typical way of achieving the same result).

Comment: @MT0 do you mean using a sys_refcursor variable as an out parameter, calling the proc the printing that variable?

Comment: Use the `SYS_REFCURSOR` variable as an `OUT` parameter, call the procedure and then loop through the variable to get the result set.

Comment: @M10, does node-oracledb support dbms_ouput.putline()? If it doesn't, how to get data from the loop?

Comment: Something like this: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/node-oracledb-070-now-supports-result-sets-and-ref-cursors

Comment: @M10, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are passing the string `execute ...` to the database.  But `execute` is not a SQL keyword - it is a SQL*Plus command.  So the database doesn't understand it and gives an error.  Instead do `begin viewSystemUsers() end;`.
- For ease of programming use async/await, not callbacks
- Review the node-oracledb example [impres.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/impres.js) becuase this shows the use of Implicit Results (which is what `dbms_sql.return_result()` is).
- Review the node-oracledb example [plsqlproc.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlproc.js).

You code could be like:

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
}

let sql, binds, options, result;
sql = `begin viewSystemUsers(); end;`;
binds = [];
options = { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT };

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
    console.dir(result, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```